# Clang -Wunused-const-variable in C vs. C++

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++

A file with just a const declaration, like so:

```
const int genericRC = 0;
```

when compiled with the clang C++ front end warns about this unused variable.  However, the clang C front end is silent about this:

```
$ cat x.sh
clang   -c src/x.c   -Wall -std=c11
clang++ -c src/t.cpp -Wall -std=c++11

$ ./x.sh
src/t.cpp:1:11: warning: unused variable 'genericRC' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const int genericRC = 0;
          ^
          1 warning generated.
```

Is there any fundamental difference in C vs. C++ const for const static scoped variables of this sort, or is this just a warning that happens to be implemented in the clang C++ front end, but not in the C front end.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Why do you expect identical syntax implies identical semantics? And `const` is a qualifier, not a scope.

Comment: @Olaf: I see no expectations here, only a perfectly reasonable and well-posed question.

Comment: @Olaf.  Because this statement is so simple I did not expect any language specific semantics.  I understand that const is a qualifier.  I was saying that this variable was statically scoped (the answer below by M.M. shows that this scoping assumption is actually the root of this particular difference).

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: The question is clearlyx rooted in the assumption C and C++ behave the same for identical features.

Comment: @PeeterJoot: There is no "static scope" in the C standard at least. And the answer does not use this term for good reasons. Linkage is something very different than scope. May i suggest you use the well established standard terms?

Comment: @Olaf: If the OP were to assume that without questioning it, they wouldn't be here asking us for the facts. You're being unreasonable IMO. This is a rare example of the perfect "[tag:c] [tag:c++]" question: let's celebrate that, not complain about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ this has internal linkage so the compiler can know it is unused. In C it has external linkage so it might be used from another translation unit, therefore it would be premature to warn.

Comment: Actually, clang has this issue, as -Wunused-const-variable is part of -Wall.  In my 30 year old C code, there's a file globals.c which holds mostly global constant variables.  These are pulled into other files via "extern" declarations in a header that ALL files include.  globals.c omits these lines via an #ifdef.  However, since some variables are only used by other files, not inside globals.c itself, it mistakenly thinks they are "unused" and throws a fit when trying to compile with C++ (to modernize things).